# Passing self.request.get("profile_pic") Null from Objective C

Tags: python, objective-c, webapp2

I cannot figure this out how to check for this being pass Null from Objective-C via POST

In Objective-C:

```
NSData *profile_pic_data = nil; (this does not change)
...
//Profile Pic Data
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"profile_pic.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:profile_pic_data]];
...
NSLog(@"profile_pic_data = %@", profile_pic_data); //RETURNS (null)
```

In Python:

```
...
user_profile_pic_data = self.request.get("profile_pic")
...
if user_profile_pic_data:
   #IT RUNS THIS CODE
else:
   #IT SHOULD RUN THIS CODE
```

If I print out user_profile_pic_data after it's set by self.request.get("profile_pic") it doesn't show anything.

I have tried:

```
if user_profile_pic_data:
if user_profile_pic_data is not NONE:
if user_profile_pic_data is not NONE and != '':
```

Nothing seems to work.

Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, but here:

```
NSData *profile_pic_data = nil;
```

You're setting `profile_pic_data` to `nil`. You're then appending your POST data to `body`, and then you're NSLogging `profile_pic_data` again. Since you're never actually setting it to anything other than `nil`, that's why it outputs as nothing.

Maybe you want `profile_pic_data` to actually have content? You can populate it from a `UIImage` using

```
NSData *profile_pic_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage);
```